# Combing Multiple RDD's in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 4 data of type RDD[Double,Double]. 
I want to join them together and want output of type RDD[Double, (Double,Double,Double,Double)] but using join function I'm getting output as RDD[Double, (((Double,Double),Double),Double)].
Here just want to clearify that first value in each data is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply map the values to the expected type:

```
val original: RDD[Double, (((Double,Double),Double),Double)] = // ...
val res: RDD[Double, (Double,Double,Double,Double)] = 
  original.mapValues { case (((d1, d2), d3), d4) => (d1, d2, d3, d4) }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I need to convert this RDD[(Double,(Double,Double,Double,Double)] into labeled Data for fitting logistics Model on this. Can you help with this?

Comment: Post a new question. Me or somebody else may help :)